# Don't understand the output of program with a switch block

Tags: c, switch-statement, fall-through

I want to understand the output of this code, specifically the 2 last lines of the output (lines 4 and 5).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double x = 2.1;

    while (x * x <= 50) {
        switch ((int) x) {
            case 6:
                x--;
                printf("case 6, x= %f\n ", x);

            case 5:
                printf("case 5, x=%f\n ", x);

            case 4:
                printf("case 4, x=%f\n ", x);
                break;

            default:
                printf("something else, x=%f\n ", x);
        }

        x +=2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First you should make the code *readable* by properly indenting it.

Comment: I don't see any output

Comment: You could use a nice code editor to properly format your code so that other people could read it easily. It is always said that code is more often read than executed.

Comment: You should notice that sme `case`s don't have `break`

Answer (score 1):

Without a break statement, the code at the end of one case will fall through into the code of the next case.

So, when `x` reaches the value 6.1, since `x*x` is still less than 50, you hit `case 6`, and with no break statement, you also enter the `case 5` and `case 4` code. So, the value 5.1 (the result of decrementing `x`) is printed 3 times.

This is a good opportunity to stress that you should compile your code with all warnings enabled. With `gcc -W -Wall`, your program will generate the following warnings:

> ```
> .code.tio.c: In function ‘main’:
> .code.tio.c:12:17: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
>                  printf("case 6, x= %f\n ", x);
>                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> .code.tio.c:14:13: note: here
>              case 5:
>              ^~~~
> .code.tio.c:15:17: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
>                  printf("case 5, x=%f\n ", x);
>                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> .code.tio.c:17:13: note: here
>              case 4:
>              ^~~~
> ```

If your code is intentionally wanting to fall-through to the next case, `gcc` will honor a comment annotating that intent. The warning will then not be emitted.

```
    switch ((int) x) {
        case 6:
            x--;
            printf("case 6, x= %f\n ", x);
            // FALLTHROUGH
        case 5:
            printf("case 5, x=%f\n ", x);
            // FALLTHROUGH
        case 4:
            printf("case 4, x=%f\n ", x);
            break;

        default:
            printf("something else, x=%f\n ", x);
```